# Why holding a pointer of MonoClass returned by mono_class_from_name crashes at some point?

Tags: c++, mono

It's my first time to use mono library.
I am holding a pointer returned by `mono_class_from_name`, and I found that my application will crash after some days running.
I was trying to figure out the reason but I can't because the Mono Library Code is too huge to read for me. It seems that the class pointer's name and name_space have already freed. I think that the GC may be reallocating the class but I am not sure.

Comment: please paste the stacktrace of the crash

Comment: "and I found that my application will crash after some days running" - congratulations on staying up for so long! ;-)